Compilar librerias en asp.net
Actualmente tengo varias librerias que he creado para reutuilizarlas en varios proyectos, lo que hago es agregar la referencia a esa dll cuando ya esta creada en determinado momento.
Mi duda es la siguiente: cuando hago un cambio en una libreria y la compilo, tengo que volver a publicar mi proyecto para visualizar el ajuste que he aplicado. Si es correcto como lo estoy haciendo? o hay alguna manera de que mi proyecto publicado tome automaticamente el cambio realizado? o esta pregunta es incorrecta?
Actualmente desarrollo en asp.net c#
Les agredezco su respuesta
Nota:
Mi duda se basa en lo siguiente: cuando en php o en una version de asp classic, se usan las referencias a archivos con un include, etc.. y al cambiar un valor en un archivo externo, los cambios se visualizan inmediatamente en los archivos donde se llaman esas funciones externas.

Porque esos son lenguajes interpretados, no compilados.. Tenes que volver a publicar la libreria, eso si.. y si esos otros proyectos llevaban la libreria, tambien vas a tener que volver a publicarlos para que tomen la nueva version...

Gracias con eso comprendo mas lo que necesito hacer entonces. le agradezco
